# How to have a three column home page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, layout, user-friendly

The home page of this site will have basically a 3 column layout.

I can create these as either content or blocks. I like using content because its easy for the user to understand, they login to the site, they browse to the page they want to edit, they click edit, but with blocks they have to go into Administer > Blocks etc

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be managing the actual content as nodes(content) and then looking at blocks(or something like it) to arrange them how you like in your template regions.

If you are looking at creating custom home and/or landing pages, you might also want to look at http://drupal.org/project/panels - it can be a little heavy, but quite powerful for arranging content into columns and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're asking...
Administer > Blocks is for moving the blocks around into regions / disabling them, not really for creating content.

You can use the Node as Block module to easily turn your nodes into blocks, and they would still edit it from the content administration section.

Or, you could create a blank block, and in its associated template file (block-whatever.tpl.php) embed the node (node_embed, pretty much what the Node as Block module does) or query for it with a view and embed that (views_embed_view)

Or, if you're using views, you could create a view that queries for the node(s) you want and create a block display for that.

When you're actually building the Drupal site, you should consider what paradigm you're most comfortable with since there are so many ways to get your content together.

Answer (score 0):

i would say boxes will help you. http://drupal.org/project/boxes

Answer (score 0):

Many themes have block edit links/images as a part of them.  Fusion is one such example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Panels for layout and block editing, and also to download a version of [open atrium](http://openatrium.com/). The layout management is uses is much easier than the administer blocks pattern.